# AngularJS: Initialize a controller for each directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a directive 'pForm' so that I can easily create instances of forms inside of html pages via tags:

```
<p-form></p-form>
```

Each form will consist of the template: templates/form.html
connected to an instance of the controller 'form' in the module 'forms'.

With that said, here's how I tried to approach it:

**Main Module (in dependencies - forms module):**

```
angular.module('mainModule', ['forms'])

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

**Forms Module:**

```
angular.module("forms", [])

.controller("form", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    alert("init");
}])

.directive('pForm', function() {alert('directive');
    return {scope: {data: '=data'}, templateUrl: 'templates/form.html'};
});
```

The html file inits ng-app="mainModule", and I place in the html's body the following:

```
<p-form></p-form>
```

the alert 'directive' works, but the controller is not instantiated (no "init" alert).

I imagine I got the concept of directives somewhat backwards. Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your directive to this:

```
.directive('pForm',function(){alert('directive');
return {
    scope:{
       data: '=data'
    },
   templateUrl:'templates/form.html',
   controller: 'form'
};
});
```

that will associate the controller to the directive

Comment: Also, remove the alert('directive').  that may be causing an issue.  If you want to verify it is being instantiated you can add this to the return statement: link:function(scope,element,attrs){alert('directive');}

Comment: On plunkr everything worked as expected.

http://plnkr.co/edit/RTMEgZg20A1XhyjVBkgZ?p=preview

I can ZIP the isolated problem for you, would you be able to go over it?

Comment: yep, go ahead and zip it up

Comment: Obviously it was something stupid, old angular version. Thanks for the help :)